# Why is `keyof T` type lost when creating a new object?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with mongoose queries which I wrap in more abstract functions. I get problems with typisation, which can be broken down to the following issue:

```js
function x<T extends object, K extends keyof T> (
  obj: T,
  key: K
) {
  // Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to
  // type '{ [Q in K]: string; }'.(2322)
  const y: {[P in K]: {[Q in P]: string}}[K] = { [key]: "ho" };
}
```

This error makes no sense because the type constrained is very clearly and explicitly met. Why is this type info lost? How does TS even assume the type of the key is `string`. It could also be `number` in the general case, right?!

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwDwBVEFNlS2AEwGdE4AjAKy2gBpEBpbXfYxAaywE85hF0A+RAAoAUIlKUAXHxpj2XafREBKRAG85EBESiJO0tQG0ACohhJ6AXQOGAimaTHriHQCdzAcwC+Xw1cQAvOqIhhyczgBEABZwEYheANwiXkA)

Comment: The basic issue is a longstanding TS bug at [ms/TS#13948](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).  But your code isn't correct either, since `x` is only of type `{[K in keyof T]?: string}` or possibly `{[K in keyof T]: {[P in K]: string}}[keyof T]}`. Try `x({a: 1, b: 2}, "a"}`; the type of the inner `x` (variable named same as function, blergh) is `{a: string, b: string}` but you've assigned `{a: "ho"}`.  If you can fix up the logic error then I can answer with a link to ms/TS#13948 (or possibly point to an existing q). Does that fully address the q or am I missing something?

Comment: If you think that my edit is more precise now (thanks for the hint), could you write up an answer? Knowing that this is a known issue already helps, of course, but an answer I can accept

Comment: You can call `x({a: 1, b: 2}, Math.random()<0.5?"a":"b")` and `y` will supposedly be `{a: string, b: string}` but the value will not be. Now you either want `{[P in K]?: string}` or `{[P in K]: {[Q in P]: string}}[K]`. Maybe it's not a big deal (if it's unlikely that `K` will be a union) but it's still a complication and one of the reasons that ms/TS#13948 hasn't been fixed yet. I'm happy to write up an answer but I'm not sure if you want to leave your types as-is or [edit] them (and if you do edit, consider folding it into a single coherent question and not a series of updates). Thoughts?

Comment: I'll need some free time to really think this through. I'll get back to you once I've done so. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited it. Neat trick to come this far! I completely missed that unions will cause trouble here. It's tough to keep these cases on the radar all the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a longstanding bug or limitation in TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948), whereby a [computed property key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) whose type isn't a single string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) gets widened all the way to `string`, resulting in an output type with a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

So if you have `{[k]: ⋯}` where `k` is of a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html),

```
function foo<K extends string>(k: K) {
  const o = { [k]: 1 };
  /* const o: { [x: string]: number;} */
}
```

or where `k` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types),

```
{
  const k = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b"
  const o = { [k]: 1 };
  /* const o: { [x: string]: number;} */
}
```

or where `k` is of a *pattern [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types)* as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598):

```
{
  const k: `xyz${string}` = "xyz123";
  const o = { [k]: 1 };
  /* const o: { [x: string]: number;} */
}
```

your object will have a string index signature despite the fact that there almost certainly exists a more specific type that would work.

The problem is that an index signature is just so *simple* compared to the "correct" type.  Presumably you need something like a *distributive object type* of the form `{[P in K]: {[Q in P]: V}}[K]` where `K` is the type of `k` and `V` is the type of `v` in `{[k]: v}`.  (The "obvious" `Record<K, V>` fails in cases where `K` might be a union type.)  This is the type you've arrived at in your question.  But such a type is fairly complicated and is difficult for the compiler to reason about in the abstract.  This is one of the reasons the issue hasn't been resolved yet: they don't want every computed key to take more compile time and result in overly-complex types.  Refer to the GitHub issue for more in-depth information.

So until and unless this issue is dealt with, if you want to see a distributive object type you will need to write it yourself, and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the value is of that type... as you've done in the question code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=4&pln=21&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUIUnvscQWWfAPbBQAuSA1kgLxICyI9AFgHQAnEMAAm1MAAoAlEgA8SAAx8ArEgD8SAEQhNSAFxaARptKUkNOo2ps8SANpMAugYCMSAL4BuU5QD0AKnNaBiRqA1x7AA8DBgEAS2AAc2ckYABXMEMIAU93JH9fHw8iMgAzNOB4ejjaJFLqalkAaSQISPoIUSgkWITEgD4JJgMmmQozCxDrdgiHFLcvIuIAoMtQ8KiY+niklPTM7Nz8wsp3EvIl1ZDhpAADSIBPLAASXF6k91ubTUesFwAmADMmm8ZiuVhssycrg8oLMK0mVg2dmiPW2fT2GSyOTyBSKZ1MBOI5Uq1VqkVkABVWu1OiJutRDAArCBVAA0SBabQ6XWYEAe1FKSEpgyKjKZBkpbKKTH5I1MYyKAgg9DSAmAtgc-JSmh41F0eRA3VmAAUkAlOSlZgBFc0ak0pd6JDweOxNRyeJC+XxyAC0vqQTLSISNUGy9EJJURSAeNkiEgiIFcHMMBn+Hg5XF4gmEYkkMnkSlUGm0ugMmmMUjh3vBMY2SbRO0SnryAB9bKnG30W-h3EA)